# how to create proportional image height/width

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

So, I want to have an image resized to 30% of its original height/width. Pretend you don't know its height or width, how would you go about it using only CSS/HTML?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update:**

Using a `display: inline-block;` wrapper, it's possible to make this happen with CSS only.

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">
    <img src="your-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.holder {   
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;    
}

.holder img {
  width: 30%; /* Will shrink image to 30% of its original width */
  height: auto;    
}​
```

The wrapper collapses to the original width of the image, and then the `width: 30%` CSS rule on the images causes the image to shrink down to 30% of its parent's width (which was its original width).

Here's a [demo in action](http://jsfiddle.net/MBLyT/1/).

---

<strike>Sadly no pure HTML/CSS way to do it as neither is geared to perform calculations like that.</strike>  However, it's pretty simple with a snippet of jQuery:

```
$('img.toResizeClass').each(function(){

    var $img = $(this),
        imgWidth = $img.width(),
        imgHeight = $img.height();

    if(imgWidth > imgHeight){
        $img.width(imgWidth * 0.3);
    } else {
        $img.height(imgHeight * 0.3);
    }
});
```

Comment: good idea, but not "using only CSS/HTML", anyone got THAT solution?

Comment: @AbishaiGray figured out a CSS only way to do it for width.

Answer (score 53):

If you need a quick inline solution:

```
<img style="max-width: 100px; height: auto; " src="image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; " src="image.jpg" />
```

i am using percent to max-width and very nice