# adjust image size proportional to Width and height

Tags: php, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create proportional image height/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380252/how-to-create-proportional-image-height-width)

The height should be adjusted proportional so that the resulting
thumbnail is not distorted. But as far as I know there is no such attribute like

```
<IMG SRC=...... WIDTH=70 HEIGHT="Adjust proportional to Width">
```

PHP or css..any one pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can also use this syntax.

```
<IMG SRC=...... style="width:70px; height:auto;">
```

Comment: Inline styles are generally considered to be very inflexible, and very poor code style. What if this needed to be applied to tens or hundreds of images? What if the exact width needed to be changed? Both of these problems would be solved easily by using IDs or classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add the `width` attribute in CSS instead...
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NbzDK/

html

```
<img src="whatever.jpg" class="scaled" />
```

css

```
.scaled{
    width: 300px;
    /* height will adjust automatically to fit */
}
```

Comment: but this will not adjusted proportional to height right?

Comment: Check the example. I see a 400x400px image next to a 300x300px image next to a 200x200px image, and they were all resized only using the CSS `width` property and nothing else.