# how to resize the image in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in imageDataUrls" >
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-ng-repeat="imageDataUrl in row" >
        <img alt="img" class="img-responsive"data-ng-src="{{imageDataUrl.url}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am showing the image using data URLs, but how can I get the current height and width in pixel to resize it proportionally in angular js?

I have some algorithm to resize it independently

Comment: you don't need angularjs to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380252/how-to-create-proportional-image-height-width

Comment: If you just set width or height the image should be resized proportional

Comment: I have some algorithm to resize it independently. I want to trigger that function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what data imageDataUrl has in it but you can get the image dimensions in JavaScript easily:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/';
```

Comment: but I'm using   FileReader();

Comment: Will this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491193/getting-width-height-of-an-image-with-filereader

Answer (score 1):

as pointed by mvermand comment, you can just add CSS to your class or directly height/width attributes.

```html
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in imageDataUrls" >
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-ng-repeat="imageDataUrl in row" >
        <img alt="img" class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/2000px-SNice.svg.png" width="300"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

If using only height or width, the other attribute is calculated to respect the image proportions.

Now, regarding the size you want, you can also use percents - like `width="100%"` to use the full width.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to resize proportionally, why not resize using CSS percentages?

CSS:

```
.smaller {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Your Code:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in imageDataUrls" >
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-ng-repeat="imageDataUrl in row" >
        <img alt="img" class="img-responsive smaller" data-ng-src="{{imageDataUrl.url}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get/set the height and width properties with `angular.element("selector").height` or `width`.

Comment: I want to trigger a function on ng-repeat  with the current element

Comment: add your function in the ng-init attribute and give the data object as parameter. if you really need the element itself (not only source) compile it in your controller with angular $compile. and so on.